# using different authentication schemes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i'm stucked on a problem and i don't know how to solve it.

i want to add two different JWT authorization methods to my API. don't ask me why, reasons.

in my startup.cs i added

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer("firstJwt", options =>
    {
        options.Audience = "FirstProtectedApi";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mySecret")),
            ValidIssuer = "WebApiTest",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        };
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("secondJwt", options =>
    {
        options.Audience = "SecondProtectedApi";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mySecret")),
            ValidIssuer = "WebApiTest",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true, 
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        };
    });

services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("FirstProtectedApi", "SecondProtectedApi")
            .Build();  
    });
```

and this code *should* work.

my problem now is, in the controller.
i have, for testing purpose, two different logins. how do i call the first or the second authentication schemes on login so that i can navigate to protected routes only available to FirstProtectedApi or SecondProtectedApi?

even some documentation would be awesome!

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> services
>     .AddAuthorization(options =>
>     {
>         options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
>             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
>             .AddAuthenticationSchemes("FirstProtectedApi", "SecondProtectedApi")
>             .Build();  
>     });
> ```

When using the `AddAuthenticationSchemes()` method, the params should be the authentication scheme, so change the above code as below:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes("firstJwt", "secondJwt")
                .Build();
        });
```

> my problem now is, in the controller. i have, for testing purpose, two
> different logins. how do i call the first or the second authentication
> schemes on login so that i can navigate to protected routes only
> available to FirstProtectedApi or SecondProtectedApi?

In the controller, if you want to use the special scheme, you could use the `[Authorize]` attribute's `AuthenticationSchemes` property. Or you can create policy for each scheme, the use the `[Authorize]` attribute's `Policy` property. Code like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "secondJwt")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
```

More detail information, you could refer the following links:

[Use multiple JWT Bearer Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694383/use-multiple-jwt-bearer-authentication)

[ASP.NET Core Using Multiple Authentication Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719181/asp-net-core-using-multiple-authentication-methods/54727678)

[Use multiple authentication schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-multiple-authentication-schemes)

Comment: thank you! i was banging my head and couldn't find a solution! thank you for the links as well, time to study! :D